# How to Filter rds Instances by Tag Value that is Date Validator with Lambda Function with Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

My Python knowledge is not good --> I am trying to stop rds instances that have the tag Key=ttl and Value = older than today (<today's date). My code does show to have run successfully but the results are not as wanted. I would like to get printed `stopInstances` or  `No rds instances to shutdown.`.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Log:
[image]

Code:

```
import boto3
import time
from datetime import datetime
# Example RDS Instance tags: 

#define boto3 the connection
rds = boto3.client('rds')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print ("Check RDS's tags")
    
     # Get current time in format yyyy-mm-dd
current_time = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

     # Search all the instances which contains ttl filter 
instances = rds.describe_db_instances()

stopInstances = []   
# startInstances = []   

     # Locate all instances that are tagged ttl.
for instance in instances["DBInstances"]:
        
         tags = rds.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=instance["DBInstanceArn"])
            
         for tag in tags["TagList"]:

             if tag['Key'] == 'ttl':

                 if tag['Value'] < current_time:

                     stopInstances.append(instance["DBInstanceIdentifier"])
                     rds.stop_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=instance["DBInstanceIdentifier"])    
                    
                     pass

                 pass


     # shut down all instances tagged to stop. 
if len(stopInstances) > 0:
         # perform the shutdown
      print ("stopInstances")
else:
      print ("No rds instances to shutdown.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change my tags, and the sign of the validator (`if tag['Value'] < current_time:`). Once this is fixed, the code is working fine.

```
import boto3
import time
from datetime import datetime
# Example RDS Instance tags: 

#define boto3 the connection
rds = boto3.client('rds')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print ("Check RDS's tags")
    
     # Get current time in format yyyy-mm-dd
current_time = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

     # Search all the instances which contains ttl filter 
instances = rds.describe_db_instances()

stopInstances = []   
# startInstances = []   

     # Locate all instances that are tagged ttl.
for instance in instances["DBInstances"]:
        
         tags = rds.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=instance["DBInstanceArn"])
            
         for tag in tags["TagList"]:

             if tag['Key'] == 'ttl':

                 if tag['Value'] < current_time:

                     stopInstances.append(instance["DBInstanceIdentifier"])
                     rds.stop_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=instance["DBInstanceIdentifier"])    
                    
                     pass

                 pass


     # shut down all instances tagged to stop. 
if len(stopInstances) > 0:
         # perform the shutdown
      print ("stopInstances")
else:
      print ("No rds instances to shutdown.")
```